# regex pattern to match first 2 numbers in a string

Tags: regex

Can anyone help with this one please

I need a regex pattern to check *the first 2 numbers* match either `01` or `02` or `03` or `07` only

Comment: Can you given an example of what kind of input you expext, and what your expected results would be?

Comment: It is for telephone numbers. I need to check the first 2 digits match either a UK landline code or UK mobile number :)

Comment: Hey @stribizhev this is not a duplicate of Learning Regular Expressions.  This is a specific question.

Comment: Yes, "gimme regex pleaz" specific. Must be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^0[1237]
```

- `^` - the start of the string
- `0` - a zero
- `[1237]` - a character set which matches one of the listed